# Show that $f: \mathbb{Z} \to n\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(m) = mn$ is bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f: \mathbb{Z} \to n\mathbb{Z}$ defined as $f(m) = mn$ is bijective such that $f(m_1 + m_2) = f(m_1) + f(m_2)$, $\forall m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

To be bijective, must be injective and surjective.

1. injective:
   $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$
   $ xn = yn \implies x = y$
   Thus, is injective.
2. surjective
   Let $y \in n\mathbb{Z}$. We must show that $y=f(x)$.
   $y=f(x) \implies y=nx$
   Since $\forall nx$ follow that $nx \in n\mathbb{Z}$.
   Thus, is surjective.
3. $f(m_1 + m_2) = f(m_1) + f(m_2) \implies$
   $n(m_1 + m_2) = nm_1 + nm_2 \implies$
   $nm_1 +nm_2 = nm_1 + nm_2$

Is this answer ok?

Comment: No, that would be $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ you're thinking of. He's correct.

Comment: Got it Deleting comment.

Comment: It is ok.  There are a few things I'd tweak though.  For example, you want to show that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$... so you might say $f(x+y)=n(x+y)=nx+ny=f(x)+f(y)$.  The string "feels" nice and is fairly readable.  The way you have it, it sort of looks like you assume you have what you want.

Comment: For surjective, what you might say is let $y\in n\mathbb{Z}$ (so $y=nx$).  Then there exists an $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x)=y$ since $f(x)=nx=y$.  Your solution again feels a little backwards... you don't know right away that $y=f(x)$... you do know that $y=nx$ for some $x$ and conclude that $y=f(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $z \in n\mathbb{Z}$ this mean that z = kn for some k $\in \mathbb{Z}$, so we have $k = \frac{z}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $f(\frac{z}{n}) = z$ since z is arbitrarily element of $n\mathbb{Z}$ so it must be surjective.

To get injectivity let $f(q) = f(m)$ $\rightarrow$ qn = mn so by cancelation law we have q = m and you are done homomorphism is easy.

Answer (score 2):

What is your argument for injectivity? It looks like you just wrote down what you wanted to be true without any justification. Surjectivity looks good.

Comment: Injectivity proof only uses cancellation of multiplication in the naturals. (no, downvote wasn't mine...)

Comment: Great, so say that if it's what you're using!

Comment: Is oki the last part of the question? I did not understand that "such that"?

Comment: Well it's always good to write out words to explain what you're doing instead of just symbols, but it looks like you have the right idea: just using the distributive property to show that the function is additive.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative strategy: define $g: n\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ by:

$g(k) = \dfrac{k}{n}$ (you may have to explain *why* $\dfrac{k}{n}$ is an integer).

Show that $g \circ f$ is the identity function on $\Bbb Z$, and $f \circ g$ is the identity function on $n\Bbb Z$.